# Facebook Insights - retrospective demographics

Tags: facebook

I need to pull monthly Reach Demographics and Engagement Demographics off Facebook Insights, but I need them to be retrospective (the last 24 months, approx).

FB doesn't seem to allow this at the front-end. Is it something I could achieve?

Any advice would be much appreciated - I'm at my wits' end.